# How to convert c++ get function code to python used in an opencv algorithm

Tags: python, c++, opencv

I would like to convert the following c++ code to python. But i cant seem to find an equivalent for line 7: MapProjec* mapProj = dynamic_cast(mapPtr.get()).

```
static void calcHomographyPixel(const Mat& img1, const Mat& img2)
{
    static const char* diffpixel = "Difference pixel registered";

    Ptr<MapperGradProj> mapper = makePtr<MapperGradProj>();
    MapperPyramid mappPyr(mapper);
    Ptr<Map> mapPtr = mappPyr.calculate(img1, img2);

    MapProjec* mapProj = dynamic_cast<MapProjec*>(mapPtr.get());
    mapProj->normalize();
    cout << "--- Pixel-based method\n" << Mat(mapProj->getProjTr()) << endl;

    Mat dest;
    mapProj->inverseWarp(img2, dest);
    showDifference(img1, dest, diffpixel);
}
```

What I got so far is the following;

```
def calc_homography_pixel(img1, img2):

    mapper = cv2.reg_MapperGradProj()
    mapp_pyr = cv2.reg_MapperPyramid(mapper)
    map_ptr = mapp_pyr.calculate(img1, img2)

    map_proj = cv2.reg_MapProjec(map_ptr) # the issue is how to the map from the pyramid cal.
    map_proj = map_proj.normalize()

    dest = map_proj.inverseWarp(img2)
```

Advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: you don't need to cast, in python there are no type declarations.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Yeah, but in this case it seems to be complicated by how OpenCV wraps the C++ equivalent. It seems to expose `cv2.reg_Map`, and then its derived class `cv2.reg_MapProjec`. The `calculate` returns what Python sees as `reg_Map`... and that doesn't have `.normalize` (this is only implementation specific to that particular derived class).

Comment: That is right @DanMašek In order to use the .normalize() function, we need to cast the pyramid to a MapProjec. cv2.reg_MapProjec expects an Ptr<cv::UMat>. Do you perhaps know how to obtain this from the reg_Map object?

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but in case someone in the future needs it, maybe you can try:

```
map_proj = cv2.reg.MapTypeCaster_toProjec(map_ptr)
map_proj.normalize
```

This is from: https://answers.opencv.org/question/225512/how-to-port-image-registration-c-code-to-python/